# Venn diagram with $3$ sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKEl7.jpg
I wanted to know the notation for the shaded regions in the 3 questions. See image by clicking link
I got $(A \cap (B \cap C))\setminus(A \cap B)\setminus(A \cap C)$ for the top image and don’t know others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple notation is to use X' for all the elements not in the set X. You can then specify any region in the Venn diagram using intersections e.g. $A\cap B'\cap C$ specifies elements which are in $A$ and in $ C$ but not in $B$.

To combine several different regions then just use unions e.g. $(A\cap B')\cup C$.